# OnRowCommand not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

I can not get OnRowCommand to fire. anything look wrong? This is for displaying a database from a sql server with links coming from each of the rows. It is built in c# using MVC and visual studio 2010

I have no idea what could be wrong with the program, I have enabled ViewStateMode on both this page and the site.master page, and tried editing it for way too long, does anything look wrong?

by the way this is the first time any have us has worked with c# MVC or asp.net, so the code might be a bit sloppy in that regard.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Teamsone.Models.Student>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Registration
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<h2>Classes offered for Next Semester [Spring 2012]</h2>

<script runat="server">

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

  // Create a new ListItem object for the contact in the row.     
  ListItem item = new ListItem();
  item.Text = "weeeee!";

  ContactsListBox.Items.Add(item);
}

</script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" allowpaging="true" DataKeyNames="SectionKey"
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableViewState = "true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FacultyKey" HeaderText="FacultyKey" 
            SortExpression="FacultyKey" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SectionKey" HeaderText="SectionKey" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="SectionKey" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseKey" HeaderText="CourseKey" 
            SortExpression="CourseKey" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SectionDay" HeaderText="SectionDay" 
            SortExpression="SectionDay" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SectionTime" HeaderText="SectionTime" 
            SortExpression="SectionTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SectionSemester" HeaderText="SectionSemester" 
            SortExpression="SectionSemester" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SectionYear" HeaderText="SectionYear" 
            SortExpression="SectionYear" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ClassroomKey" HeaderText="ClassroomKey" 
            SortExpression="ClassroomKey" />
       <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Link" 
              commandname="Add" 
              text="Add"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:listbox id="ContactsListBox" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="200px"/>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [NextCourse]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: So far, it doesn't look to me like you're actually *using* MVC, you seem to be stuck in webforms mode.

Comment: You might want to read up on MVC, since (like Anthony Pegram said), it looks like you're trying to use webforms, not MVC. Check out http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC uses views only to render the html - so in this case, if you use ASP.NET web-page or user-control as a view then it will be used only for rendering the output html.

The entire post-back model including control events will not work because the POST requests will be intercepted by ASP.NET MVC controllers. The ASP.NET page does not get chance to handle the request (and to subsequently raise the post-back events).

Further, you don't seems to understand ASP.NET MVC model and you want to start reading more about it - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337884.aspx